# Editing HTML content in Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Editing HTML content in Google Sites

I have a small project in mind but cant seem to get past this one obstacle.
Having trouble getting the HTML content of this Google Sites Page and adding a single line too it.  So if one would keep refreshing the page the 'Hello World' line would keep adding itself over and over.  I have noticed that the original code that embeds the gadget gets altered quite a bit too.

```
function doGet() {
  var app  = UiApp.createApplication();
  var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
  var html = page.getHtmlContent();
  var main = page.setHtmlContent(html + '<br>Hello World<br>');

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getHtmlContent()` will return all the html markup and tags.  So, you're trying to set "Hello World" after all the tags have been closed.

Throw a `Logger.log(html);` in there to see what you need to get at and change.  Ultimately you'll need to replace the text you want within the html instead of just adding a line to the end.

Answer (score 0):

its by design that the html keeps chsnging every time you run it. your script permanently modifies the site.
instead you need to publish a htnlservice appscript and insert it on the site.